# Which best model I have to use to calculate standard deviations?

Tags: machine-learning, standard-deviation, model, accuracy

Suppose that I run the same experiment 5 times.
Now, suppose that each model of each experiment has the best accuracy in different epochs. For example:

1. Model1: best accuracy after 10 epochs
2. Model2: best accuracy after 50 epochs
   and so on...
   Now, I want to calculate the standard deviations of the accuracies. Which model and which epoch accuracy I need to consider?
   For example, suppose that among the 5 models, model1 achieves the highest accuracy. It reaches this accuracy after 10 epochs. Do I have to use the accuracies of the other models after 10 epochs, or I have to consider the best accuracy of the other models (so after a different number of epochs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should choose the epoch number that best works for the particular model. In the end, each model has different complexities and may need different number of epochs to learn the data. Equating the epochs does not make sense.